# Handling CLOB as JSON String in Oracle DB C#

Tags: c#, string, oracle, clob

I am trying to store a json string in my oracle database as the CLOB datatype. My insert statement seems to be working:

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

var jsonString = ...; // some json string

var jsonToBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString);
var clob = new OracleClob(connection);
clob.Write(jsonToBytes, 0, jsonToBytes.Length);

var query = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO DATATABLE (ID, JSON) VALUES ");
query.Append($"(DATATABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :1)");

var sqlString = query.ToString();
var command = new OracleCommand(sqlString, connection);

var jsonParam = command.Parameters.Add("JsonString", OracleDbType.Clob);
jsonParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
jsonParam.Value = jsonToBytes;

var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Dispose();
connection.Close();

return rowsAffected;
```

My problem is getting the CLOBs back as strings. It is a requirement that I get multiple rows back at once. I'm thinking that I need to get the json string back as bytes then translate to a string, but I'm lost at how to get the value back as a byte[]. this is what I have so far:

```
var queryString = $"SELECT * FROM DATATABLE";
var command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var modelList = new List<RowModel>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var jsonByte = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("JSON"));

    modelList.Add(new RowModel{
        ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
        JsonString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString((byte[])jsonByte);  // This is failing
    });
}
```

But, of course, this fails with the error that the jsonByte cannot be converted from a string to a byte[]. I feel like I am very close to getting the clob data back as a string, though. Is the insert incorrect and affecting the data retrieval?

Any help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am using the package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess if that helps at all

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally figured it out and I'm just going to answer it here since it took me literally two days to see anywhere that mentioned that you can insert strings into CLOB fields...just like a string.

My insert had all references to parameters, encoding, etc. removed:

```
var query = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO DATATABLE (ID, JSON) VALUES ");
query.Append($"(DATATABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, '{jsonString}')");
var sqlString = query.ToString();
var command = new OracleCommand(sqlString, connection);
var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
// And so on
```

Then for the data retrieval:

```
var queryString = $"SELECT * FROM DATATABLE";
var command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var modelList = new List<RowModel>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    modelList.Add(new RowModel
    {
        ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")),
        JsonString = (string)reader.GetOracleClob(reader.GetOrdinal("JSON")).Value
    });
}
```

Hopefully this can help someone. It took me way too long to figure out something so simple.